# How to autoload a relationship with Adonis with find or findOrFail?

Tags: adonis.js

Is there a way to autoload a relationship with findByOrFail (or any other method like find etc.)?

In the code below, the method `with()` is not defined.

```js
async show({ params, response }) {
  try {
    return await Company.findByOrFail('domain', params.id).with('websites')
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)

    switch (error.name) {
      case 'ModelNotFoundException':
        return response.notFound({ message: 'companies_show_not_found' })

      default:
        return response.badRequest({ message: 'something_went_wrong' })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do it with query like:

```
await Company.query().where('domain', params.id).with('websites').firstOrFail()
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like the way to go!

Answer (score 2):

Adonis 5 has support for [hooks](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/models/hooks) which are run during a pre-defined life-cycle event.

So ideally you could do something like this.

```js
class Company extends Model {
  
  @hasMany()
  public static websites: HasMany<typeof Website>

  @beforeFetch() 
  @beforeFind() 
  public static fetchWebsites(query: ModelQueryBuilderContract<typeof Company>) { 
    query.preload('websites')
  }
}
```

Then when you fetch the company, the results will include the relation.

```js
Company.all()
```

```js
{
  'name': 'company_name', 
  'websites': [
   {
     'name': 'my site', 
     'url': 'my.site'
   }
   ...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the cleanest solution is to use a `globalScope`.

```js
class Company extends Model {
  static boot() {
    super.boot()

    this.addGlobalScope(function (builder) {
      builder.with('websites')
    })
  }

  websites() {
    return this.hasMany('App/Models/Website')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use relation like this

```
async show({ params, response }) {
  try {
    const relationdata= await Company.findByOrFail('domain', params.id)
return await relationdata.websites().fetch()
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)

    switch (error.name) {
      case 'ModelNotFoundException':
        return response.notFound({ message: 'companies_show_not_found' })

      default:
        return response.badRequest({ message: 'something_went_wrong' })
    }
  }
}
```